# Is clouldflare cdn only for static FILES? What about constant RESPONSES?

Tags: caching, immutability, cdn, cloudflare

My server's replies are immutable. Can I somehow cache them to prevent output bandwidth usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudflare is able to cache almost any kind of response, when configured to do so. One method is to use a page rule set to "Cache Everything", and "Origin Cache Control" alongside setting `Cache-Control` header in your HTTP response -
https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/about/cache-control

You'll want to read through their full documentation however to get the full picture on how / why their caching behaves the way it does, along with all your options -
https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/

Comment: I see, thank you!